# "StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet" After Process.GetProcessById()

Tags: c#, process

I have this code in a method:

```
int startApp()
{
  ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
  proc.FileName = "File.exe";
  proc.Arguments = "someArguments";
  proc.RedirectStandardInput = false;
  proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  proc.UseShellExecute = false;
  proc.CreateNoWindow = true;

  Process p = Process.Start(proc);
  Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()); // Here it works!

  return p.Id;
}
```

Then I run this code using the process Id returned by the previous method:

```
void readText(int processId)
{
  Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
  Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()); // Here does not work!
}
```

It fails saying `"StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet"`.

Somebody has any idea why I can't read from the `Process.StandardOutput`?

Comment: You should return the whole `Process` object from `startApp` and using that in `readText`, not re-obtain it by process ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that; you can only ever use Standard{Input, Output, Error} if you started the process, and even then only from the process object that started it.

Arrange to make the process object used to start the process available to the code that needs to read standard output.